# How do I put the output of a file in the email body as opposed to an attachment?

Tags: linux, email, mailx

I'm using Amazon Linux.  I found the following for sending the contents of a file as an attachment

```
cat /tmp/output.txt | mailx -s "Subject" "myaddress@gmail.com"
```

But what I want to do is send the contents of the file as the body of the email, as opposed to an attachment.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You man use "lower level" `sendmail` program.

```
#!/bin/sh
# cat - ... <<END - cat reads "here document" via its stdin
# empty line after email headers IS REQUIRED

cat - /tmp/output.txt <<END | /usr/sbin/sendmail -- myaddress@gmail.com
Subject: Subject
To: myaddress@gmail.com

END
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't your example sends just `/tmp/output.txt` as message body. Maybe content of this file is formatted as an attachment?

Try with:

```
echo "Test message" | mailx -s "Subject" "myaddress@gmail.com"
```